# Flink Kafka SInk Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Attempted to write a non-default producerId at version 1

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, sink

version:
cdh(6.2.1),flink(1.13.1), kafka(2.1.0-cdh6.2.1)

data pipeline:
kafka(source) -> flink -> kafka(sink)

The submitted Job is running normally. After I savepoint, an exception occurs when I restore it through savepoint.

```
2021-11-22 16:39:52,556 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Job Flink Streaming Job (daf7707813d79b884b2c7b1897801248) switched from state RUNNING to FAILING.
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by FixedDelayRestartBackoffTimeStrategy(maxNumberRestartAttempts=0, backoffTimeMS=3000)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:207) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:197) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:188) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:677) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:435) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:305) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:212) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:77) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:158) ~[data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:26) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:21) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$class.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:21) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:170) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:517) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:225) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:592) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:561) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:258) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:225) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:235) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [data-access-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies5.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.UnsupportedVersionException: Attempted to write a non-default producerId at version 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Kafka version is rather old, maybe you need to downgrade the `kafka-client` version in your fat jar. Or even better: maybe you can try to upgrade your Kafka to something more recent. Kafka fixed quite a few things in their transaction handling in 2.5+.